# SQLite tuples equality comparison

Tags: sql, sqlite, tuples, comparison-operators, row-value-expression

With PostgreSQL and MySQL it is all right to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (column1, column2) = ('value1', 'value2');
```

When I tried the same thing on SQLite3, it gave me an exhausting error message:

```
Error: near ",": syntax error
```

From the SQLite documentation I can't figure out whether it supports tuples or not. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596973/using-in-with-sets-of-tuples-in-sql-sqlite3

Comment: Eh, sorry, must have overlooked that one, I only found several unrelated ones. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `WHERE expr` and as we can see in the syntax diagram for `expr`,
a column (expr) followed by a comma isn't supported.

**expr:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do like this:

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1 = 'value1' AND column2 = 'value2'

Comment: This works for the case given but not where you want to fetch multiple rows like this using IN. To cover that you'd be stuck doing a monster `(x = ? AND y = ?) OR (x = ? AND y = ?) OR ....`